# How to have a kind of dynamic field inside the json payload on a ApiController?

Tags: web-services, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I need that a part of the `json` schema to be variable. How do I declare a field that will be bind to the dynamic part of json?

I'm using net core 6.0 and `Newtonsoft` serializer.

Example:

```
{ 
  id:1,
  ...
  dynamicData: //from here the json can be any valid json structure. the type is unknow.
}
```

The payload class would be:

```
public class SomePayload {

   public int id {get;set;}
   public dynamic dynamicData {get;set;}
}
```

Using the `dynamic` type the json part is put in a object inside an object.

This means that if I send this payload:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "dynamicData": {"x":1}
}
```

the `dynamicData` will get `{{"x":1}}`

Declaring `dynamicData` a string and parse it inside the controller method should work but
there should be a clean way to do this that i am not aware about it.
The type doesn't have to be the `dynamic` type.

For the sake of completeness, here the controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void submit(SomePayload payload)
    {
    }            
}
```

and the program.cs file to set `NewtonsoftJson` as the api serializer (.net core versions previous to 6 use the startup class instead):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the value data type?

Comment: no, because i don't know the type at project time. I need to be able to receive extended data in any valid struct json object

Answer (score 0):

I did this by declaring the property with the type object and deserializing it to a model that matches the dynamic data format.

Dynamic model

```
public class SomePayload {

   public int id {get;set;}
   public object dynamicData {get;set;}
}
```

Model to deserialize dynamic data

```
public class modelThatMatchesDynamicData {
    
   public int x {get;set;}
   public string y {get;set;}
}
```

Request body

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "dynamicData": {
        "x": 47,
        "y": "string"
    }
}
```

Desserializing

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void submit(SomePayload payload)
    {
        var variable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelThatMatchesDynamicData>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
    }            
}
```

Is it works for you?

Comment: That is not very dynamic because it requires an previous know model class